# Masm32 Terminate Program by Key Press

Tags: string, input, terminate, masm32

I have done some research and still cannot find a valid answer on how to terminate an assembly program by pressing and F1-F12 key from the terminal.

I have a simple program like so:

```
.data
prompt1 BYTE "Please Input a sentence.",0Dh,0Ah,0


.code
Main Proc
mov edx,OFFSET prompt1
call WriteString

call ReadString
exit
main ENDP
main END
```

I've been hearing about this INT16h to check whether a key is pressed, but how is this implemented in the most simple example? Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Found a good example for you from The MASM Forum ([posting here](http://masm32.com/board/index.php?topic=826.msg7079#msg7079)).  The code is not mine, but I've written bits like this before.

```
        .XCREF
        .NOLIST
        INCLUDE \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc
        .LIST

;#########################################################################

        .CODE

;*************************************************************************

_main   PROC

        print   chr$('Press Esc to Exit'),13,10
        jmp short kloop2

kloop1: INVOKE  Sleep,40

kloop2: call    InKyb
        jz      kloop1

        push    eax
        cmp     ah,0
        jz      kloop3

        push    2020h
        jmp short kloop4

kloop3: mov     ah,20h
        push    eax

kloop4: print   esp
        pop     edx
        pop     eax
        push    eax
        print   right$(uhex$(eax),4),13,10
        pop     eax
        cmp     eax,1Bh
        jnz     kloop2

        exit

_main   ENDP

;*************************************************************************

InKyb   PROC

;Polled Keyboard Input - DednDave 8, 2010
;
;This function returns a keystroke in EAX if there is one in the buffer.
;If the buffer is empty, the function returns immediately.
;
;If the keyboard buffer is empty, AH = 0, AL = 0, ZF = 1.
;If the stroke is a regular key, AH = 0, AL = key char, ZF = 0.
;If the stroke is an extended key, AH = extended key, AL = E0h, ZF = 0.
;If the stroke is a function key, AH = function key, AL = 0, ZF = 0.
;
;ECX, EDX are not preserved.

        call    crt__kbhit
        or      eax,eax
        jz      InKyb1

        call    crt__getch
        and     eax,0FFh
        jz      InKyb0

        cmp     al,0E0h
        jnz     InKyb1

InKyb0: push    eax
        call    crt__getch
        pop     edx
        shl     eax,8
        or      eax,edx

InKyb1: retn

InKyb   ENDP

;#########################################################################

        END     _main
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using the Irvine32 Library.  Just use the `ReadKey` function from the library:

```
.data
prompt1 BYTE "Please Input a sentence.",0Dh,0Ah,0

.code
Main:
    mov edx,OFFSET prompt1
    call WriteString

    call ReadString

    push    VK_F23
    call    WaitForKeyPress
    exit

WaitForKeyPress proc VKey:byte
ReadIt:
    mov     eax, 10
    call    Delay
    call    ReadKey
    jz      ReadIt    
    cmp     ah, VKey    
    jne     ReadIt
    ret
WaitForKeyPress endp
END Main
```

For my keyboard, I need to pass `VK_F23` to exit on <kbd>F12</kbd> keypress.  You can try passing `VK_F12` to `WaitForKeyPress` and see what happens on your system